# How to make two Pebbles talk to each other. Preferably using javascript with Pebble.js, but open to using PebbleKit sdk or Standard C Pebble

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch

I'm creating my first application with Pebble using Pebble.js from this github project

https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs

The point is that I'm trying to have an application that runs on two different pebbles that sends messages to a server and send a message back to each pebble depending on what each pebble says. I was wondering if there was a simple way to do this? I spoke to a friend and he said to try using 'Node.js' but then I mentioned Pebble, and he said that you couldn't use that with Pebble.

I have never programmed in Javascript or Pebble before, but I assumed it would be easier than doing it with the C sdk (I'm pretty good at C though, so if it's easier to do it that way I'm all ears).

Sorry if I'm not being clear, if you want me to clarify anything just tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use some kind of server. Firebase is a pretty fun and easy to use solution for that type of problems.

See [this description of 'Clock' (a multiplayer app)](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-16-winners-use-firebase-hackillinois.html) for example.

And this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419315/including-an-external-javascript-library-in-pebble-js-file) for more information on how to use Firebase in CloudPebble.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't make a bluetooth connection between two pebble.

You should connected each pebble to a different smartphone/computer. From here you can send what you want from internet or GSM.

The bulk of this project is the smartphone app, not the pebble app.

Look at the notification part in the PebbleApp store on your smartphone, you will find some app like Whatapps for Pebble. This could help you to understand how to do your app.