# Accessing firebase using cloud pebble (Pebble.js)

Tags: javascript, firebase, pebble-watch, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I've been trying to figure out a way to access data from firebase to display in a pebble app, using cloud pebble. I'm not quite sure how to do so as I'm relatively new to javascript and the pebble platform.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet, or running to any specific problems? I cannot answer your question, but generally SO users expects a minimal attempt before answering questions.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I've tried to make sense of this( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419315/including-an-external-javascript-library-in-pebble-js-file ) post, I understand how it works with adding an external library or a json file, but I dont really see how this helps me with firebase

Answer (score 1):

You can require remote URI's using the following syntax:

```
require('//cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.9/firebase.js');
```

The other (more traditional) way to work around this is to copy-paste the source code of the library you want to use at the top of your JavaScript file.

Your best bet to use Firebase for the Pebble is to use the C SDK. There are lots of great examples on how to do this. Here is one. https://github.com/tyhoff/clock

Comment: I've written a more complete [Introduction to Firebase and Pebble](http://abe.ghost.io/firebase-pebble/) on my blog, with a special shoutout to you Kirby :)